# ANR | Android 11(30) | Broadcast of Intent { act=android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF flg=0x50200010 }

Tags: android, react-native, android-broadcast

I keep getting this ANR reported on the Play store console. This issue is occurring on Android 11 only. Can anybody please help me out with how can I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like some of your BroadcastReceiver(may be from library like ads or something else) call to goAsync() and not call to PendingResult.finish() in acceptable time window ( https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver#goAsync() )